# Cant hide status bar

Tags: ios, swift, hide, statusbar

Cant hide status bar. Is it possible on iPhones with an eyebrow?

In ViewController:

```
...
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(prefersStatusBarHidden) // true
}
...
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Added View controller-based status bar appearance in .plist and set it to YES.
Nothing...

Answer (score 2):

Method 1: Go to Your info.plist file.
Add a key called “View controller-based status bar appearance” and set its value to NO.
Method 2: Go to your app delegate and write this line of code.

```
UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
```

Example:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {    
// Override point for customization after application launch.    
 UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true    
return true
}
```

Comment: Deprecated in iOS 13

Answer (score 0):

Add **View controller-based status bar appearance** in .plist and set it to **YES**.